# Got problem deploying docker-compose service(port issue)

Tags: docker, port

I want to deploy a service that will allow me to use **Spark** and **MongoDB** in a **Jupiter notebook**.

I use docker-compose to build up the service, and it`s as followed:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

volumes:
    shared-workspace: 
    networks:
    spark-net:
        driver: bridge

services:   
  spark-master:
    image: uqteaching/cloudcomputing:spark-master-v1
    container_name: spark-master
    networks:
        - "spark-net"
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "7077:7077"
    environment:
        - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
        - "PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
        - "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"

  spark-worker-1:
    image: uqteaching/cloudcomputing:spark-worker-v1
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
        - spark-master
    networks:
        - "spark-net"
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    environment:
        - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
        - "PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
        - "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"

  spark-worker-2:
    image: uqteaching/cloudcomputing:spark-worker-v1
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    depends_on:
        - spark-master
    networks:
        - "spark-net"
    ports:
        - "8082:8082"
    environment:
        - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
        - "PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
        - "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: 'mongo'
    networks:
            - "spark-net"
    ports:
            - "27017:27017"

  mongo_admin:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: 'mongoadmin'
    networks:
            - "spark-net"
    depends_on:
            - mongo
    links:
            - mongo
    ports:
            - "8091:8091"


  jupyter-notebook:
    container_name: jupyternb
    image: jupyter/all-spark-notebook:42f4c82a07ff
    depends_on:
        - mongo
        - spark-master
    links:
        - mongo
    expose:
        - "8888"
    networks:
        - "spark-net"
    ports:
        - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
        - ./nbs:/home/jovyan/work/nbs
        - ./events:/tmp/spark-events
    environment:
        - "PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
        - "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
    command: "start-notebook.sh \
              --ip=0.0.0.0 \
              --allow-root \
              --no-browser \
              --notebook-dir=/home/jovyan/work/nbs \
              --NotebookApp.token='' \
              --NotebookApp.password=''
             "
```

And the result is something like this:

[image: output of "docker ps" command]

I don`t know why. Even I set these` 2` services to listen to a different port.

They are using `8081/tcp` at the same time, which caused them both to crash.

I want to solve this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just include the output of `docker ps` in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

mongo-express seems to need port 8081 internal, so use another external port to be able to login to the webui.

http://localhost:8092 would then be something like this:

```
mongo_admin:
  image: mongo-express
  container_name: 'mongoadmin'
  networks:
    - "spark-net"
  depends_on:
    - mongo
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "8092:8091"
```